# VS2010 / Target Framework = 3.5 / Building on Continuous Integration Server

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I'm checking into upgrading to VS2010.

Our production servers only have 3.5 Framework and it will be 6-9 months before they are updated.

We also have a Continuous Integration Server, running CruiseControl.NET (CC.NET).
It has the 3.5 Framework on it as well.
Our implementation of CC.NET mainly calls msbuild.exe MySolution.msbuild.  (We encapsulate most of the build logic into .msbuild files fyi)

Inside the .msbuild file, the following is the "Build" syntax:
  **< Target Name="Build" DependsOnTargets="Checkout">
    < MSBuild Projects="$(WorkingCheckout)\MySolution.sln" Targets="Build" Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration)">
      < Output TaskParameter="TargetOutputs" ItemName="TargetOutputsItemName">< /Output>
    < /MSBuild>
  < /Target>**

(A few spaces added to make it display here)

===========

I know the VS2010 can "Target" the 3.5 Framework.

My question is what happens when I have a VS2010 dev machine, and I check the VS2010 .sln and .csproj(s) files into source control (svn, btw).....will the CC.NET machine ~~which only have the 3.5 Framework installed on it........be able to build the .sln ?

I guess I could test it, but the catch22 is that I don't have VS2010 (yet).
So I'm asking before I try (the trial or a real install.

.............

Any ideas what will happen?

I guess the crux question is, what will happen.

**c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\MSBuild.exe "MyVS2010SolutionFile.sln"**

??

My hopeful goal would be, allow the developers to have VS2010 (now!), and it still be "ok" for the CC.NET machine and the Production Servers which will only have the 3.5 Framework on them for the foreseeable future.

Just to be clear, developers NEVER create deployable builds.  Only the CC.NET machine produces builds that will be pushed as production builds.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so.

Here where I work, we have VS2010 with projects targeting 3.5 being built by CruiseControl.net. The only 'gotcha' I believe, is that the v4.0 of msbuild is being used - but because the csproj files target 3.5, everything runs together nicely.

It was a pain making sure CCtray wasn't barfing at us though.